# compare variable with user input in php always returns false

Tags: php, string, if-statement, compare

I'm making a verification page that compares two variables

the first one is a random code that have been generated previously from a python script and took the result to php variable under the name $code example of the output (8063D0A7) it is an 8 characters of numbers and letters

the second one is the user input ($verf)

when the user clicks submit ($code) and ($verf) should be compared if it is true then transfer to other page if not then try again will be showed

I have tried a lot of ways but it always shows false in any case and any input

```
<?php
session_start(); ///starts a session and getting the variables from another page 

echo "E-mail has been sent to " ;
echo $_SESSION['email'];  ///gets $email from another page


echo $email , "   ";
echo $_SESSION['code'];  ///gets the $code from another page


$email = escapeshellarg($_SESSION['email']);  ///make an arg to put in bash script


$code = escapeshellarg($_SESSION['code']);


$addr = shell_exec("./test.sh $email $code"); ///execute bash script to send $code to $email


?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<body>  
<h2>E-mail Verfication</h2>
<form method="post" action="">  
Name: <input type="string" name="verf" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
    $verf = $_POST['verf'];
    if ($verf == $code) {
        echo "Correct!";
         header('Location: 12.php');
    } else { 
        echo "Wrong!";

    }

} else {
    echo "please fill the verification";
}



 echo $verf;
 echo $code;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

i think there is a problem identifying the variables for example takes $code as a string and $verf as an other type of input so it will always be false i don't know i'm new to php help PLZ .. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple - it is because you use `escapeshellarg()`, which adds single quotes around a string and quotes/escapes any existing single quotes (check manual: [PHP escapeshellarg](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.escapeshellarg.php)

So, in your case:

```
// lets say:
$_SESSION['code']="abc";

// then you do:
$code = escapeshellarg($_SESSION['code']);

// this means that now, $code is actually "'abc'" instead of "abc"
echo $code;

// so, if
$verf = "abc";

// then of course, $code is NOT the same with $verf;

echo $code == $verf ? "correct" : "incorrect";
```

So, in your case, you should change this line:

```
//$verf = $_POST['verf'];
$verf = escapeshellarg($_POST['verf']);
```

Next time, try to debug it by just echoing: $verf vs $code.

**EDIT**. Response to comment:

To remove empty spaces in your data you can use: [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.trim.php)

```
$code = "  A1B3 ";
$code = trim($code);
echo $code;
//A1B3
```

Or, to remove all chars that are not desired (ex. chars that are not A-Z or 0-9), you can use: [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$code = "  A1B3?!#@! ";
$code = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9]/", "", $code);
echo $code;
//A1B3
```

Comment: thank you now i understand what happened ... the problem now is the $verf1 is      ' 940E8A83'  and $code is '940E8A83 '  you see there is a space in the start and in the end of every variable i don't know it's source can you help me with it ?

Comment: I see. I added some explanations to my answer. Try to use one of those functions in your script.